# Is there a standard truth table for $\alpha\models\beta$?

Tags: logic

From what I understand, $\alpha\models\beta$ means that if $\alpha$ comes out true, so does $\beta$. i.e., $\alpha$ entails $\beta$.

This got me thinking, I know that there are truth tables for $\alpha\implies\beta$, $\alpha\lor\beta$, etc. Is there a standard truth table for $\alpha\models\beta$?

Comment: Might be relevant for you: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12816/difference-between-implication-conditional-and-logical-entailment

Comment: The "truth value" of $\alpha\models\beta$ is not a function of a particular valuation, so assigning it a truth table wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: $α \vDash β$ means that $α$ is a [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of $β$.

There is no "standard" truth table for it, but of course you can use truth table: write a t-t for the formulas $α$ and $β$ and check if in every line of the t-t where $α$ is evaluated to TRUE also $β$ is TRUE.

If so, this will show that the second is consequence of the first.